# Date/Time Range Validator for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, validation

It looks like the standard asp.net 2 RangeValidator control doesn't allow times. e.g. 01/01/2008 12:00 is not accepted in my range, even though it should be valid. If I remove the time it works as expected.

Is there a validator out there that allows for date/time format?

### Update

We don't have Ajax extensions. Ideally, would like a preexisting control or a regular expression to use with CustomValidator. Validation should be client side, the server validation part is easy.

### Solution

We used this RegExp:

http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=610

Comment: The AJAX controls are a free download from Microsoft's asp.net site: http://ajax.asp.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom validator and perform the check manually.

[Here's a quick example](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/) or you can Google "asp.net custom validator".  If you exclude the "ControlToValidate" property then you can validate against multiple fields.

Comment: Do you have regex that can do this? I was hoping I wasn't the first to come across this problem.

Comment: I don't have one off the top of my head.  I've used regexes from http://regexlib.com in the past with success.  If you are just matching a string for the correct date format there should be one there.  This one looks like it might fit: http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=610