# webforms validation yyyy/mm/dd/time without JS

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have validation

```
   <asp:CompareValidator
            ID="CompareValidator4" runat="server"
            Type="Date"
            Operator="DataTypeCheck" ForeColor="Red"
            ControlToValidate="RequiredDateTextBox"

            ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date.">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
```

How I can do yyyy/mm/dd + time correct in field, now It accept only yyyy/mm/dd .
 For example I want 1987.12.12 00:00:00, but it accept 1987.12.12

Comment: Please include what you have tried and what hasn't worked.

Comment: @EBrown I edit record

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date/Time Range Validator for ASP.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263779/date-time-range-validator-for-asp-net)